# CakePHP, overwrite recipient setted

Tags: cakephp-3.0, mailer

I have a website done with cakephp 3.x to test, I have imported all data from old website and same time user emails.
I need to test it with some colleagues but I want that all email in output will go to online one recipient (our company mail).
A way to do is putting conditions in all function in each mailers, but there is a way to overwrite recipient before send? Like an event "beforeSend" or similar?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any built-in method for doing that. Maybe make your own mailer class extending the standard one, and just have a "from" function that ignores the passed parameter and calls `parent::from` with your test address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg
There isn't a built-in method, I did a Trait to overwrite the setTo, setCc and setBcc function.
Trait check in config file if enabled or not.